# Jquery Validation plug-in dependency from Radio buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I need some inputs to be required only if certain options are checked in another  input (radio). In short, if Type 1 documents is chosen, I need type 1 field number to be obligatory. It's easier to visualize through this jsfiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/kbhatd51/2/

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance

```
<form id="registerform" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label >Type of Document</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="radioForm" id="fis" name="tipop" value="0" > <label for="fis"> Type 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" class="radioForm" id="jur" name="tipop" value="1" > <label for="jur"> Type 2</label><br>
  </div> 
  <label for="tipop"> Number</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <fieldset id="cpf1">

      <label for=cpf1>Type 1 No.:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control"  placeholder="000.000.000-00" name="cpf" id="cpf" >
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="cnpj1">
      <label for=cnpj1> Type 2 No.:
        <input type="number" class="form-control"  placeholder=" 00.000.000/0001-00" name="cnpj" id="cnpj"></label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit!"> 
</form>
```

JS validate:

```
$("#registerform").validate({
  rules: {
    cpf: {
      required: "#fis:checked"
    },
    cnpj: {
      required: "#jur:checked"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `required` method needs to return `true` for the field to be required.
So you can simply pass a function to `required` which will check if the `radio` element is `checked`

> [**required method**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#required-method)
>
> **required( dependency-callback )**
>
> *Type: Function()*
>
> *The function is executed with the element as it's only argument: If it returns **true**, the element is required.*

```
$("#registerform").validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    cpf: {
      required: function(elem) {
        return $('#fis').is(":checked")
      }
    },
    cnpj: {
      required: function(elem) {
        return $('#jur').is(":checked")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Check out the [**-- JSFiddle Example --**](https://jsfiddle.net/eahswLn8/) here.

Comment: well, thats was awkward. hahah thanks man, it works just fine